# Excel table that has manual project cost forecast entered in but months that have passed have the cells updated from an accounting database of actuals

Tags: microsoft-excel

I cannot seem to search the right thing to find a solution, so hopefully this helps.

I have a table of projects and their associated forecasted cost broken down by month. Every project gets a forecast of spending throughout the year. However, when a month is wrapped up, accounting has a database which will have the actual spend on said project.

I am trying to make an Excel spreadsheet that would overwrite historical month estimates for specific projects into actual values. I can't make an elaborate formula in each cell that checks current date and looks up the database, as the forecast numbers are entered by less tech savy people so they kind of have to stay as just a cell with regular $$$ input. I suspect this gets me into some kind of hidden macro, but I am all ears on any possible solutions.

Thanks in advance for taking a look at this.

[image: sample of the table]

Comment: And what have you done to achieve this? This is not a free scripting site. It is a site that helps people who have helped themselves. So this site can help you with your code if you have any issues with your code. Feel free to share your code and we can help you debug your code. But we cannot code anything for you from scratch.

Comment: I don't think VBA is necessary, perhaps powerquery to pull in the actual data. Then I would have a third sheet/table that pulls in BOTH the budgeted and actuals. The benefit is it allows variance analysis that wouldn't be available by overwriting data as you suggested.

Comment: Thank you both for taking a look at this. 
I resorted to having two columns for each month with some quick macro running buttons to hide the columns with the actual values. This allows the forecast numbers to just be free cells with no formulars and then still updates the actuals based on an external database. Then can always unhide those and have variance analysis.